Parsing a function call statement using Participle golang
I want to create a simple parser for parsing function calls i.e. function(arg1, arg2, kw1=v1, kw2=v2)
I started fairly simple by creating a parser grammar for the Key and Value as a Property struct and wrapping that around a function struct, as followed.
var (
    initLexer = lexer.MustSimple([]lexer.SimpleRule{
        {`Ident`, `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_\d]*`},
        {`String`, `(?:\\.|[^"])+`},
    })
    parser = participle.MustBuild[Function](
        participle.Lexer(initLexer),
        participle.Unquote("String"),
    )
)

type Function struct {
    Name       string      `@Ident`
    Properties []*Property `"(" @@* ")"`
}

type Property struct {
    Key   string `@Ident "="`
    Value string `@String`
}

func main() {
    out, err := parser.ParseString("", "myfunction(foo = bar)")
    repr.Println(out, repr.Indent("  "), repr.OmitEmpty(true))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

But when I run this I'm getting this output:
unexpected token "foo = bar" (expected "(" Property* ")")

It is only able to parse until myfunction as Function.Name but not going beyond that. Is there something wrong with the lexer regex that I provided?
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.
